# Form not submitting on ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I'm comparing the value of the input field entered by the user to the value of the mysql DB (using an Ajax request to the checkAnswer.php file). The request itself works fine, it displays the correct "OK" or "WRONG" message, but then it does not submit the form if "OK". Should I put the .submit() somewhere else?

HTML code:

```
            <form id="answerInput" action="index" method="post">
              <div id="answer-warning"></div>
              <div><input id="answer-input" name="answer" type="text"></div>
              <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">      
              <div><button type="submit" id="validate">Valider</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JS code

```js
$("#validate").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.post(
        'includes/checkAnswer.php',
        {            
           answer : $('#answer-input').val(),
           id : $('#id').val()
        }, 
        function(data){ 
            if(data === '1'){ 
                 $("#answer-warning").html("OK");
                 $("#answerInput").submit();
             }
            else{
                 $("#answer-warning").html("WRONG");
             }         
        },
        'text'
     );
});
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gomabulubu/1/edit?html,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you set your button type as `submit`. Why?

When you do `$("#validate").click(function(e){`, you implicitly replace the default submit behavior of the form.

As you want to interfere in the middle of the process for extra stuff, I suggest you change the button type to `button` or simply remove the `type` attribute.

Then the `$("#validate").click(function(e){` will alter behavior of `click`, not the `submit` of form.

Comment: Ok so: if I just remove the type attribute, nothing happens. If I change to "button", it works fine but only when pressing Enter on the keyboard, not by clicking on the Validate button. Any idea? :)

Comment: Ok I think I get it. There was a hidden input field with name="submit", and that interfered with the jquery .submit() function. It seems to be working now!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="answerInput" action="index" method="post">
    <div id="answer-warning"></div>
    <input id="answer-input" name="answer" type="text">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">      
    <button onlcick="validate()">Valider</button>
</form>
```

/******** JS ************/

```
function validate(){
var post = {};
    post['answer'] = $('#answer-input').val();
    post['id'] =  $('#id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/checkAnswer.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {data: post},
        success:function (data) {
            console.log('succsess');
        },
        error:function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('failure');
        }
    });
}
```